# Whats wrong with my mdi window

Tags: powerbuilder

I am new to powerbuilder 12.5, no matter which tutorial I read , my mdi window is different then the other programs, the code i am using is:

OpenSheet(normalWindow,MDIWindow)

but the outcome is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYdBO.png

The window is fixed and cannot be dragged, even if I change the coding into:

OpenSheet(normalWindow,MDIWindow,Original!)

please help me, I am stuck for days

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use PowerBuilder.NET. Since WPF doesn't (natively) support MDI, this tabbed solution is what Sybase engineers have done to support OpenSheet(), primarily to support code that has been ported forward from previous Win32 versions. Moving forward into a WPF paradigm, you'd need to ditch the idea of MDI.

If you're dedicated to the idea of MDI, you can move to PowerBuilder Classic and create a Win32 target.

The debate between going PowerBuilder Classic with a Win32 target or PowerBuilder.NET with a WPF target is long and involved, and I'm not inclined to dive in right now. I will say this much: These days, particularly when multi-monitor configurations are becoming more common, I find the traditional business app choice of MDI becoming more and more questionable. More than twenty years after Microsoft and others brought MDI to the masses, I find users and even programmers confused by what MDI has to offer. I've even seen programmers with implementations that assumed that users could not switch to another sheet without closing the last sheet they had opened. Users who aren't ardent hobbyists are at a loss at how to deal with MDI, often going to "re-open" a sheet that they've lost and have no idea how to navigate to. And, constraining your UI to one monitor in multi-monitor days makes as much sense to me as not making your UI "responsive" to higher resolutions.

You could move to Classic and build an MDI solution. Or, with Classic or .NET, you could take the opportunity to steal ideas from other desktop apps, from mobile platforms, or from even gaming platforms, and come up with a new way to present your data to your users in a way that doesn't require them to take a course to navigate. Who knows? Maybe someday when we're following this new pattern that seems so obvious now, we'll be referring to you as "that guy."

*(Sorry for the long, involved, off-topic rant. I'm waiting for the dryer to finish, and this has been brewing for a long time. And, yes, my apps have a long way to go. *grin*)*

Good luck,

Terry

Comment: Thank you for your reply Terry, may  I ask one more question, is there anyway to dock a window within a window without using mdi? I tried to use AvalonDock but it does not support windows docking but rather visual user objects docking within a window, any library should i look at?

Comment: AFAIK AvalonDock doesn't use windows, but user objects. (What I know about it comes from http://pbdj.sys-con.com/node/1947041, not first hand.) To me, that makes sense, because stuff you'd program for a window doesn't necessarily apply to a dockable pane. Now to quibble, I wouldn't call what MDI can do "docking", since I can't connect two "panes" and drag them to an independent area of the screen(s); there's a lot more power to the user with an AvalonDock solution. What's the perceived loss in not using windows? This is the 2nd question like this recently, so maybe I'm missing something.